# Evaluation of derivatives of Green's function at $t = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, greens-function

Given that $G$ is the Green's function of some $m^{\rm th}$ order ODE with homogeneous Cauchy conditions, what does then
$$
\frac{d^n G}{d t^n}\bigg|_{t = 0}
$$
mean for $n > m$? When $n < m$, $G^{(n)}(0) = 0$ by the definition.

As far as I understand, in general, $G$ is a distribution, so that $G^{(n)}$ is a distribution as well. I am confused about what sense could $G^{(n)}(0)$ have and how to evaluate it?

**Edit**

Forgot to mention that in my particular problem $G(t) = \theta(t) w_0(t)$, where $\theta$ is the Heaviside function, $w_0$ is a proper function.

Comment: You are right that $G^{(n)}(0)$ doesn't really make sense generally. A distribution or even its derivatives might however equal a continuous function locally, and if this is not the case, the onesided derivative might be defined.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my particular problem, $G(t) = \theta(t) w_0(t)$, where $\theta$ is the Heaviside function and $w_0$ is a proper function. I guess that fits to what you mention, but still can't get the whole idea.